# Flagged as low quality, declined, but I still think the question was low quality

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged a question, [mysql_fetch_row not returning full array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283744/mysql-fetch-row-not-returning-full-array), as "low quality" but a moderator declined it. I thought that the post was a low quality one and would like to know why the moderator did not.

Hopefully shedding light on this matter will avail me of the knowledge to be a better flagger in future.

My logic was that `mysql-fetch-row` is not supposed to return an array of results. If it does than its name would be `mysql-fetch-rows`.

What's your take on the situation?

Comment: The [Chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/421/whining-room) room [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) is probably a good bet, or you could try one of the main site rooms. As you've yet to hit the 500-flag level it's only a few flags to get back up to speed...if you had 700 I could understand ;)

Comment: In the future, choose the "Other" flag option and elaborate why it's low quality. Recently, SO got new moderators who might be more triggerhappy and may not necessarily see/understand what you were thinking.

Comment: For this specific question that you have indicated, I think best thing is to post an answer with correct solution, or add a comment about your thought.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "very low quality" flag is for questions that can't be salvaged through editing.

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

I don't see any evidence of that on the question you flagged.

What action did you want a moderator to take?  (You can flag as "other" and fill in the text box telling us more details about the problem and what action you recommend when the canned flag reasons aren't descriptive enough.)

Comment: I though question like that is not helpful/useful for anyone and I wanted that to be removed.

Comment: @Rifat that's what downvotes are for

Comment: @Rifat: Downvoting is fine if you think it's just a bad question, but I don't think that question is outside the guidelines in the FAQ.  Also, the "very low quality" flag should really only be used for questions that are so badly written or formatted that you can't even understand what they're asking.

Comment: @BilltheLizard hmm, thank you. I got the point :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the perfect place to ask a question about that.  Just link to the question and give your explanation of why you think it was low quality.  Other community members (and possibly moderators) will respond with their thoughts / explanations of why the flag was declined.

---

As an addendum, I don't think the post you linked is low quality at all.  It doesn't meet the requirements listed when you select the flag (I think it mentions that the question could not be recovered, even through editing).  That question has decently formatted code and a clear problem.  The OP just misunderstood / forgot how that particular function worked.

Comment: hmm, got your point.